# Nullpointer exception Java

Tags: java, exception, null, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner in Java and I have a few problems with `null`. I need help with understanding the following questions. I have answered them correctly, however I do not know the exact reason behind them.

### Question:

Suppose that tracks has been declared with type ArrayList and consider the following:

```
public Track mostPlayed() {
    Track most = tracks.get(0);
    int i = 1;
    while(i < tracks.size()) {
        Track t = tracks.get(i);
        if (t.getPlayCount() > most.getPlayCount()) {
             most = t;
        }
        i++;
    }
return most;
}
```

Suppose that a NullPointerException is thrown during an execution of the `mostPlayed` method. Assuming single-threaded execution, only one of the following lines of code is possible because of this exception. Which one?

I had picked line 2 as it seemed the only logical answer, but I would like further explanation behind it as I don't understand the concept completely.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in your copy data, and format your code with the code button. I edited your question

Comment: Ontopic: If there is an exception, there will be a line number in the exception information.

Comment: Hi sorry I am new on the website. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: That is why I had the number written on each line so the question would be easier to understand. Bascially the correct answer I have picked is Track most = tracks.get(0); not exactly sure why though

Comment: @fge: No the first track has been taken two lines before, so tracks.get(i) is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `Track most = tracks.get(0);` can throw a `NullPointerException` since the code does not show if `track` was initialized. If it was not, it will be `null` and it there is no method `get` in `null` (there is no method at all, actually).

Comment: cant line 6 'tracks.get(i)' also be null for the same reason then?

Comment: Yes, but it can't raise a `NullPointerException`, since the `tracks.get(0)` already did it.

Comment: thanks that makes sense, can you have a look at a similar question for me please regarding null and run time error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638349/runtime-error-java

Answer (score 4):

`t.getPlayCount()` can throw a NullPointerException if the ArrayList tracks contains a 'null' at some index.

and also `Track most = tracks.get(0);` can throw a NullPointerException if tracks is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object oriented programming language and Objects serve as a basic building block.

In many real life there are cases where objects cannot be created.

A null object represents a special value which says that this object does not exist.

For e.g If I say  `Person p;`. At this point java will assign null value to p. Now If I try something like `p.getName()` , obviously java will not be able to give me the name of the person since I never created one. Therefore whenever you try to access something using a variable which is null, java trows an error.

There are lots of resources covering this topic if you need a better understanding. Please note that using default/place holder values like null is a very common concept used in even non object oriented languages.

For your question above. Tracks can be null since someone can just do `ArrayList<Tracks> tracks` and never initialize it using the `new` keyword.

Furthermore you can do `tracks.add(null);` which stores a null value into the list. Therefore when you do a `tracks.get(i)` , you might receive a null value.

And as explained above invoking `get` or `getPlayCount()` can therefore cause null pointer exceptions.

I would highly recommend you read up on some of the introductory materials on Java since I believe this topic would be discussed thoroughly in such materials.