# Runtime error Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, runtime-error, println

I am a beginner in Java and I have a run time error question. I have answered it correctly, however I do not completely understand the concept behind the answer. Could someone please explain why B is the right answer to the question, thank you:

Consider the following declarations:

```
private ArrayList<String> list;
...
public void printAll()
{
int index = 0;
while (index < list.size) {
index = index + 1;
System.out.println(list.get(index));
   }
}
```

Assuming that list is not null, which one of the following is true about invocations of printAll()?

a)A run-time error occurs only if the list is empty.

b)A run-time error occurs only if the list is not empty.

c)A run-time error never occurs.

d)A run-time error always occurs.

e)A run-time error occurs whenever the list has an even length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (index < list.size) {
 index = index + 1;
 System.out.println(list.get(index));
}
```

Here `index` is incremented *before* accessing the list. So it reads one element ahead everytime. So run-time error when the list is not empty.

If the list is empty then the condition `while (index < list.size)` will fail and hence the loop code that causes the run-time error will never be executed.

Although not relevant to your question, the correct code would be to increment the `index` after reading:

```
while (index < list.size) {
 System.out.println(list.get(index));
 index = index + 1;
}
```

Comment: great that makes sense.. so if the list was empty and nothing added then it would be okay although would be completely pointless. Therefor the incrementation must occure after the method body action

Answer (score 0):

consider list have 10 items,
then indexes were 0 - 9

now when index=9

while loop check it 9<10 which is true and enters in then add 1

index become 10 which is out of bound error occured

Comment: Yes I understand that but why does the run time error occur if the list is not empty, hence B?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (index < list.size) {
 index = index + 1;
 System.out.println(list.get(index));
}
```

> case 1

: if list is empty, content of while loop will never be executed.

> case 2

:if list is not empty, accessing last element will occurs an error. Because the element at `list.size` is not there in list.

So, that error occurs only if list contains at least one element.

Answer (score 0):

The correct option is b) a run time error occurs when list is not emtpty

Explanation: We are starting from index=0, but just before print statement we are incrementing the index by 1. So, even if the condition in while is satisfied, the last index we will get index out of bounds error.

Eg. if array's size is 2 and after first iteration, index=1. Next time, inside while (1<array.size()), but then we increment the index by 1, so index=2 and when the print statement will be executed, it will throw error as array.get(2) is out of bounds because of 0 based indexing.

if the list is empty, we wont get inside while loop.